# ExecutorService invoke a method before and after each task

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

If I have:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
```

With 10 threads running:

```
scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(thread, initialDelay, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

How can I invoke a method `foo()` before each task is executed and `bar()` after each task is completed?

Comment: Are you looking for each Thread execution Or each Runnable/Callable execution? If you are looking for each Runnable/Callable execution, have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html which provides: beforeExecute and  afterExecute

Answer (score 0):

You coul try to hack something with AspectJ oder AOP. This interrupts the application flow and executes an aspect with custom methods.

Or you call `foo()` and `bar()` within your threads.

Comment: Assuming that the threads come from thirdparty libraries and I am unable to modify the code, I don't think AOP would work either?

Comment: You may overwrite the threads and the run method. execute the `foo()`method,. call `super.run()` and execute the `bar()` method.

Comment: you can overwrite the `ScheduledExecutorService` launch the `foo()` method before a thread is fired and the `bar()` method after that.

Comment: That's more like it! except I have no idea what to execute after `foo()` and before `bar()` as I'm not an expert on that class

Comment: I' am no expert either. You got a `SchudeldThreadPoolExecutor` from `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10)`. That means you have to overwrite this class and i think the schedule methods in particular. Runnable or Callable.

Comment: You don't get much ability to override anything when you use the `Executors` class methods, but if you explicitly construct a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, then you can pass in your own custom `ThreadFactory`.